# Using RANK, OFFSET and MATCH to find rank after an adjustment

Tags: excel, ranking

I have a formula that alters the margin on a premium in 'Sheet1' (column name: Adj_premium), when the premium is adjusted its relative place in the rankings of other premiums in the 'rank_lookup' table changes accordingly. Each row in the premium data in 'Sheet1' has a unique reference number (column name: UniqREF) that corresponds to a column header in the 'rank_lookup' table. What I am trying to do is return the relative rank for each row in 'Sheet1' from the values stored in the 'rank_lookup' sheet. I tried the following, but it returns an N/A;

`=RANK([@[Adj_premium]],OFFSET(rank_lookup!$B:$B,0,MATCH([@UniqREF],rank_lookup!$B$5:$JB$5,0),1,1),0)`

Thanks in advance

Ben

['Sheet1'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RsSEU.png)

['rank_lookup' table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/00BJe.png)

Comment: Sample data with expected results would make this easy to answer.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I've edited the original question and included screenshots of both pages after trying in vain to upload a spreadsheet. Please let me know if there's anything else I can do to clarify things.

Comment: If your adjustment is mutiplying each value by the same scalar, their corresponding rank shouldn't change. What do you want as output?

Comment: I'm only multiplying the values in sheet1 which are part of a particular scheme. The data in rank_lookup are policies from other providers so they are not being multiplied by the same scalar. I should have specified this earlier. Apologies...

Comment: RANK won't be the appropriate function to use here because unless the number to be ranked  actually appears in the range you get #N/A

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your data in the RANK table is in descending order, this should work:

```
=MATCH(C7,OFFSET(rank_lookup!$A$3:$A$73,0,MATCH(D7,rank_lookup!$B$2:$E$2,0)),1)
```

Comment: I think you mean ascending Fernando? Arguably better with INDEX for the same result, i.e. `=MATCH(C7,INDEX(rank_lookup!$B$3:$E$73,0,MATCH(D7,rank_lookup!$B$2:$E$2,0)),1)`